# How to join a std::thread from itself (in C++11)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost-thread, stdthread

I have a `std::thread` waiting and reading from a socket. And there is a pointer to this `thread` stored somewhere. But when something bad happens and the `thread` ends, I want it to call something that results in a function that will join this thread and then delete the pointer referring to it. (I have access to that pointer from within the thread)

I could do that in another thread but then that new thread becomes the problem.

Comment: The Join must happen in the launching thread.  Which means _that_ thread would require an event handler.  Does your launching thread have any sort of event mechanism?

Comment: how could I inform the launching thread that this thread has ended?

Comment: @Farzam However you want, there's no "one right way". The simplest way is probably a boolean protected by a mutex.

Comment: 'when something bad happens' - like what?  Why would the thread have to 'end'?  If something excepts, you can catch it in the usual way.

Comment: @MartinJames The thread can end when the socket is closed.

Comment: @Farzam: Same way your launching thread receives any other sort of event.  If you don't have any sort of event handling code, then you'll probably have to make your primary thread periodically check the state of the background thread, either using a `atomic_bool`, or the `thread` object itself.

Answer (score 4):

You could create your thread in a detached state, and make your thread lifetime dependent a condition variable and switch a boolean state on finish.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>

class A {
    private:
        void Threadfunction();
        volatile bool class_running;
        volatile bool thread_running;
        std::condition_variable cv;
        std::mutex mu;
    public:
        A();
        ~A();
        void Stop();
};
A::A(){
    class_running = true;
    thread_running = false;
    std::thread t(&A::Threadfunction,this);
    t.detach();
}
A::~A(){
    if(class_running) {this->Stop();}
}
void A::Stop() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mu);
    class_running = false;
    while(thread_running) {
        cv.wait(lk);
    }
    std::cout << "Stop ended " << std::endl;
}
void A::Threadfunction(){
    thread_running = true;
    std::cout << "thread started " << std::endl;
    while(class_running){
        // Do something
    }
    thread_running = false;
    cv.notify_one();
    std::cout << "thread stopped " << std::endl;
}
int main(){
    A a1;
    A a2;
    sleep(1);
    std::cout << "a1.Stop() called " << std::endl;
    a1.Stop();
    sleep(1);
    std::cout << "a2.Stop() not called but a2 goes out of scope and destructor is called " << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your design so that you don't have this bizarre requirement. One simple solution is to use `shared_ptr`s to a control structure that owns the thread and has other status information as well. The thread can hold a `shared_ptr` to this control structure and use it to report its status to any other interested code. When nobody cares about this thread anymore, the last `shared_ptr` to this control structure will go away and it will be destroyed.

Comment: Downvoted because: "Change your requirement" is never a pertinent to an OP.  It is not always possible to change requirements.

Comment: @JonathanBen-Avraham I cannot disagree strongly enough with the claim that an answer that is not always possible to do is not a pertinent answer.

Comment: The OP needs a solution. @Conk's post provides a solution. Your post does not. It only hints at a solution and does not say what is needed to say, that a thread cannot join itself, but that there are work-arounds when there is a requirement for a thread join to be conditioned on state information that is local to the thread. If you would state in your post what you only hint in your above comment, that a thread cannot join itself, and explain why, that would improve your answer.

Comment: @JonathanBen-Avraham Conk's answer is a design change that eliminates the requirement and not a particularly good one. The key is to change the design. Without more details, it's unlikely that examples are particularly helpful. I'd argue that's doubly true of very complex code with odd synchronization hacks and no comments.

Comment: It's not bizarre at all. I ended up here because I have the same situation. I have a thread reading and an exception occurred in the thread, not I need to exit and cleanup.